# Developing Word VSTO addin using VB.NET. Can you stop debugging without closing Word?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I can't figure out how to stop my code from running without shutting down Word. Which makes it pretty much impossible to see what my code has done to the document it is processing before it crashes.

I have Googled this issue several times. And I've looked at the MS documentation. Haven't gotten anywhere near an answer.

Comment: It would be helpful to see the code. Have you considered putting a  breakpoint or two and/or stepping through the code in debug mode.

Comment: The code isn't an issue. This is true no matter what code I'm running. Yes, I've tried breakpoints and stepping through the code. But that doesn't help because I can't access the document. When the code is running, I have no access to the document. And if I stop the code, Word and the document close. If I can't access the document after the code hits a bug, I can't figure out why the code is crashing, or what the code actually did to the document before it crashed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, since you say this happens no matter what and code doesn't matter, then the answer is: No, you can't do that. Sorry.

BUT if you want to solve it programmatically, you can do it. We just don't have enough info to tell you how to do it with your specific program.

Details follow:

No you can't stop the opens word, debug runs, word is closed when debugging stops within Visual Studio. When you hit debug (or run) Visual Studio kicks off a new instance of Word and when it is done it closes it because it is assuming that you don't want it messing with other things. Since you are programming, critcal errors that are unrecoverable are well within the realm of possibility. If there is an error of any sort that causes Word to crash, the other instances of Word, that aren't part of your programming efforts, shouldn't be affected. Same thing happens when doing ASP pages... you get a new instance of the web browser instead of it using a running instance even though opening into a new tab is even more trivial than opening a new word doc. With older version of VS even the console window closed after ending debugging, only recently can we prevent that (and implicitly use the same console window).

So assuming that "Nope, sorry, sucks doesn't it?" is an unacceptable answer, here is how you start to programmatically hook into an already open Word instance (code below assumes it is open and will give an error if not). Marshal has a GetActiveObject method that will probably work for you but you might end up tweaking your code to the point where it doesn't actually help save any time. (I am guessing you don't like the time involved on closing and reopening word every time.) Regardless if I am guessing right here is how to get going with that.

Since you didn't mention versions (and it matters here obviously) but you did mention VSTO I used .net framework 4.7.2 here because if I recall correctly, MSFT said that they weren't going to keep using VSTO with Core so you are probably on framework. If I am wrong or just behind, you can look up the code for the deprecated GetActiveObject and copy and paste it into a helper class so that you can use it - it doesn't work with .Net Core currently though.

Again, do note that this doesn't account for multiple instances of word, so it will need to be tweaked  for that if you have that scenario in play.

```
    Dim oWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    oWord = Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application")
    Console.WriteLine(oWord.Path) 'this is the instance of word, not the individual documents - it is an ApplicationClass type and it is probably what you need to be hooking into

    For Each d In oWord.Documents 'd is each document and they are all DocumentClass types ... probably just one for you but you could check for the right one in here if there are multiple documents in play
        'call your code here if you need to pass it a DocumentClass or delete this loop entirely if you can pass it an applicationClass above
        Dim dName As String = ""
        Dim fullPath As String = ""
        Console.WriteLine($"Path: {d.Path}") 'this is the path to each open document in that word instance (without file name included)
        Console.Read()
    Next
```

Note if word isn't already open you will get:
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Operation unavailable

If this doesn't work, you will need to edit this question and include code so that we can hook into it. Also note that step 1 of microsoft's tips on debugging office is to close all office apps and let visual studio open (and close) as needed. So you are already coloring outside the intended lines.

Comment: Many thanks. You answered my question in your first paragraph. I guess I should have specified that  was the type of answer I was looking for.